# How do I turn a function variable into a div id name?

Tags: javascript

This is what I have that works:

```
function content() {
   var dd = document.getElementById("stuff1")
      dd.classList.toggle('disp');

}

<li onclick="content()"></li>
```

This is what I want to do:

```
function content(x) {
   var dd = document.getElementById("x")
      dd.classList.toggle('disp');

}


<li onclick="content(stuff1)"></li>
```

But that doesn't work. What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: this is a basic request and you have been answer however i would recommend you read some basic tutorials in Javascript, you can start here http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both other answers correctly state you need to remove the quotes from your `getElementById` call so that:

```
var dd = document.getElementById(x);
```

But you **also** need to *add* quotes to your `content` call in the `onclick` handler body:

```
<li onclick="content( 'stuff1' )"></li>
```

Otherwise the `stuff1` is treated as a variable name and not a string.

Answer (score 4):

**Change these:**

```
var dd = document.getElementById("x");
<li onclick="content(stuff1)"></li>
```

**To these:**

```
var dd = document.getElementById(x); // here x instead of "x"
<li onclick="content('stuff1')"></li> // here 'stuff1' instead of stuff1
```

**NOTE:** Any name in quotes (doesn't matter in single or in double) is treated like a string, without quotes as a variable...

Answer (score 0):

You may try to remove the quotes like  this:-

```
var dd = document.getElementById(x);
```

instead of this:

```
var dd = document.getElementById("x")
```